# How can I search String value with ArrayList of String type in Java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, search-engine, contains

I have a list of cities, want to search from these cities:

```
ArrayList myCities; // list of cities 
String searchString = scanner.nextLine();

List<String> matchedCities = new ArrayList(); // an empty list for storing matched cities

for (String c : myCities) {

    if (c.matches("(?i)" + searchString + ".*")) {
        matchedCities.add(c);
    }
}
```

eg. apple if it is an element in array
currently c returns apple of if ap entered or apple but not for ppl.

This works only for if a city start with or start/initials, however I want if a user enter string from middles it should return the suggested city;

e.g. if a user enters ppl, it should return apple, or any word that has ppl whether if it starts with or contains in middles or ends with.

Comment: Did you try String::contains()?

Comment: The code you have posted would not compile.

Comment: Yeah, I did try contains() but that it doesn't give me what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String::matches` impicitly checks the entire string as if "^" and "$" anchors are applied, so a minor fix to check for a value in the middle would be to update the regex to allow any prefix `".*"`.

Also, it may be needed to put the `searchString` between `\Q` and `\E` to enable search by *string literal*, and automatically escape characters which may be reserved for the regular expressions.

```java
if (c.matches("(?i).*\\Q" + searchString + "\\E.*")){
    matchedCities.add(c);
}
```

---

Another option would be to convert both `searchString` and the element in the list to the same case and use `contains`.

An example implementation using Stream API:

```java
String search = searchString.toLowerCase();
List<String> matchedCities = cities
    .stream()
    .filter(c -> c.toLowerCase().contains(search))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Update**

To return / print the part of the word following the `search` string, `String::substring`, `String::indexOf` and `String::length` could be used: `city.substring(city.indexOf(search) + search.length())`

```java
String search = searchString.toLowerCase();
List<String> afterMatch = cities
    .stream()
    .filter(c -> c.toLowerCase().contains(search))
    .map(c -> c.substring(c.indexOf(search) + search.length()))
    .peek(System.out::println) // print the part after the search
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Programmer please visit Help Center and learn what to do [if you get a helpful answer to your  question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: how could I get the next letters, if an app enters, it should say the next letters are lle.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your comment, please elaborate it and post as a separate question.  Also looking forward to your accepting/upvoting the answer :)

Comment: If a string is an apple, eg. String s = "Apple", and searchString is pp, it should say next letter are le. currently I used  s.substring(searchString.length();

Comment: @Programmer, check the update, you should have added `s.indexOf(search)` when calling `s.substring`